# Integral over circle around branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, branch-points

I am having some problems with the integral
$$\int_\gamma \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}\;dz$$
where $s>1$ and $\gamma$ is the cirle with radius $\delta$ around $0$. This integral should approach $0$ for $\delta \rightarrow 0$.

In my book it says it's value is $2\pi i$ times the average value of $z^s(e^z-1)^{-1}$, because $i \, d\theta = \frac{dz}{z}$. I think by this something like the Cauchy integral formula with center $z=0$ is meant. The problem is that the inner function has a branch point at $0$:
$$(-z)^s = e^{s\log(-z)}$$
What exactly happens here?

The author further says the integral approaches $0$, because $z(e^z-1)^{-1}$ is nonsingular near $z=0$. Again, I have no clue what he did here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(z) =  \frac{z^{s-1}}{e^z-1}$$ where we are looking at the branch $z^{s-1}=e^{(s-1)\log z}$ for $\Im (\log z) \in  [0,2\pi]$.

$$\frac{1}{e^z-1}=z^{-1}+O(1),\qquad  f(z) = z^{s-2}+O(z^{s-1})$$

$$\int_{|z| = \delta} O(z^{s-1})dz = O(\delta^{\Re(s)})$$

(where $\int_{|z| = \delta}g(z)dz$ means integrating the analytic continuation of $g$ along the curve $\delta e^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]$)

$$\int_{|z| = \delta} z^{s-2}dz= \frac{z^{s-1}}{s-1}|_\delta^{\delta e^{2i\pi}} = \frac{\delta^{s-1} (e^{2i\pi (s-1)}-1)}{s-1} = O(\delta^{\Re(s)-1})$$

$$\int_{|z|=\delta} f(z)dz =  O(\delta^{\Re(s)-1})$$